# Onclick button center of screen

Tags: html

Here is my code for box.
Below is what it looks like in the browser. I've tried text-align: center, box-align: center, and position: relative. None of these have worked. What am I missing?
[image]

Comment: how about using `<center>` tag as  `<center><!-- your div here --></center>`

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated 20 years ago.

Comment: as long as it works :D . BTW, i clicked your sarcastic link and was surprised to find a real page.

Comment: Thank you everyone. The square is now in the center of the page. Helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you want the box to be center aligned when a button or the box is clicked.

If the box is a div...

`<div class="box" onclick="alignCenter()">
</div>`

use...

`function alignCenter(){
  var el = document.querySelector('.box');
  el.style.margin = '0 auto';
}`

**Checkout Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/onejeet/pen/mQwBNK

Comment: Happy. You liked the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function myFunction(){

 document.getElementById("myP").style.textAlign = "center";
 
}
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: #0074D9;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<center><h2>Click the Box</h2></center>

<div id="myP" onclick="myFunction()">
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```